# Family of functions which satisfies $f(\boldsymbol{x}) = 0$ if $\nabla f(\boldsymbol{x})=0$?

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

I have a Lagrangian of which I want to find the supremum in the primal variable $\boldsymbol{x}$:

$\mathscr{L}(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{\lambda})=f(\boldsymbol{x})^T\boldsymbol{a} + \boldsymbol{\lambda}^T(\boldsymbol{b}+cf(\boldsymbol{x})-f(\boldsymbol{x}))$

such that:

$\mathscr{L}:\mathbb{R}^M \times \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$

$f:\mathbb{R}^M \to \mathbb{R}^P$

In this way, the supremum will be at an $\boldsymbol{x}$ such that the gradient of the Lagrangian satisfies:

$\nabla_\boldsymbol{x}\mathscr{L}(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{\lambda})=\nabla_x f(\boldsymbol{x})^T(\boldsymbol{a} + c\boldsymbol{\lambda}-\boldsymbol{1})=0$

and it will be $\boldsymbol{\lambda}^T\boldsymbol{b}$. It is:

$$
sup \mathscr{L}(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{\lambda}) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \boldsymbol{\lambda}^T\boldsymbol{b} & \nabla_x f(\boldsymbol{x})^T(\boldsymbol{a} + c\boldsymbol{\lambda}-\boldsymbol{1})=0 \\
            \infty & otherwise
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

This statement is only truth if $\nabla_x f(\boldsymbol{x})=0$ 
 implies $f(\boldsymbol{x})=0$

So, my questions are:

1. Is there any family of functions $f(\boldsymbol{x})$ which satisfies $f(\boldsymbol{x})=0$ if $\nabla_x f(\boldsymbol{x})=0$ (appart from linear functions)?
2. Is there a more general expression for the suppremum of this Lagrangian?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by $\nabla_w$ ?

Comment: Sorry for the notation. I tried to fix it in the question. I mean $\boldsymbol{x}$ is an $\mathbb{R}^n$ input vector, and $\nabla f(x)$ the gradient of $f(\boldsymbol{x})$ w.r.t vector $\boldsymbol{x}$. If it is not clear yet, just let me know.

Comment: Like $f(x)=(g(x)-c)^2$, with $\nabla g\neq0$ everywhere and $c$ being in the range of $g$?

Comment: apologies, I don't understand the question:$ \nabla f=0$ means $f={\rm constant}$, what else is there to say?

Comment: I think he means that the zero set of $f$ is contained in the zero set of $\nabla f$

Comment: @CarloBeenakker , I mean that I want to find a function $f(\boldsymbol{x})$ which is 0 for each $\boldsymbol{x}$ where $\nabla f(x)$ = 0. i.e:

if $f(\boldsymbol{x})=\boldsymbol{a}^T\boldsymbol{x}$ then $\nabla f(\boldsymbol{x})=\boldsymbol{a}$.

As a consequence, $f(\boldsymbol{x})=\boldsymbol{a}^T\boldsymbol{x} = \nabla f(\boldsymbol{x})^T\boldsymbol{x} = 0$ if $\nabla f(\boldsymbol{x})=0$.

Comment: @PieroD'Ancona the zero set of $f$ _contains_ the zero set of $\nabla f$

Comment: @PieroD'Ancona thank you very much! The one you said, $f(x) = (g(x)-c)^2$ is useful but only let me represent functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^+$. I would need an alternative which allows me to also represent $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @jean sure contains :)

Comment: Like $(g(x)-c)^3$? I'm not sure I understand your last remark in view of your question

Comment: Some examples include $xy$ (with a single saddle) and $x\,\sin(y)$ (with infinitely many isolated saddles) and $(e^x\cos(y)-1)^2+(e^x\sin(y))^2$ (with infinitely many isolated local minima) and $x^2$ (with a curve of weak local minima extending to infinity).  I'm not sure if it is possible to have both an isolated local minimum and an isolated local maximum.  If you have a closed curve of weak local minima then inside there must be a local maximum (by compactness) but the value must be zero at both the minima and maxima so it is zero everywhere inside the curve.

Comment: @Neil: yes, as soon $n\ge2$. It's quite easy to construct a smooth function with any prescribed finite set $S$ of critical points, together with prescribed levels and Morse indices, plus, possibly, a set $S'$ of finitely many other critical points.  To kill these additional critical points  include them into an unbounded simple curve $\Gamma\sim [0,\infty)$, disjoint from $S$; consider a diffeo $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\Gamma$ which is the identity outside a suitable nbd of $\Gamma$. Then $f\circ\phi$ has exactly $S$ as a critical set, and coincides with $f$ on a nbd of $S$.